# C++ preprocessor : defer a macro call later

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

I am currently building my for_each macro. I did find some example on Stack overflow, so I take my inspiration from them, but I want to understand everything I do, so I come to ask questions ^^

I am trying to perform a "stop" recursion. So I write this code :

```
#include <iostream>

#define PRINT_SQUARE(x) std::cout << (x) * (x) << std::endl;

#define END(...)

#define MAP_END(...) 0, END
#define MAP_NEXT0(item, next, ...) next
#define MAP_NEXT(item, next) MAP_NEXT0(0, END, next) // This part for test

#define MAP_1(f, x, end) f(x) MAP_NEXT(end, MAP_0)(f, 0)

#define MAP(f, x, y) MAP_1(f, x, ())

int main() {
  MAP(PRINT_SQUARE, 5, 8);

  return 0;
}
```

This code works. However I have this line `#define MAP_NEXT(item, next) MAP_NEXT0(0, END, next)`

So, instead of doing it, I tried to replace the `0, END` by a call to the macro `MAP_END`, but without success...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define PRINT_SQUARE(x) std::cout << (x) * (x) << std::endl;

#define FORCE_EXPANDING(x) x

#define END(...)

#define MAP_END(...) 0, END
#define MAP_NEXT0(item, next, ...) next
#define MAP_NEXT(item, next) MAP_NEXT0(MAP_END(), next)

#define MAP_1(f, x, end) f(x) MAP_NEXT(end, MAP_0)(f, 0)

#define MAP(f, x, y) MAP_1(f, x, ())

int main() {
  MAP(PRINT_SQUARE, 5, 8);

  return 0;
}
```

It does not compile :

```
..\main.cpp(20): error C2065: 'PRINT_SQUARE': undeclared identifier
..\main.cpp(20): error C3861: 'MAP_0': identifier not found
```

Comment: Why are you building a for_each macro? You're using C++11, so why not use a for-each loop (range-based for loop)?

Comment: ... and you can also get very far with `constexpr` if you want your stuff to be dealt with during compiletime.

Comment: Hello, because basically I built a `is_valid` constexpr function. So I am using it like the one `boost::hana` use. However, write something like: `auto hasOperatorPlus = is_valid([](auto a, auto b) -> delctype(a + b){});` is not that pretty, that is why I am learning macro to search a simplier way to write it, even if there is some obscure preprocessing things burried behind this :)

Comment: Yeah I know, and I did get already pretty far with `constexpr` and metaprogramming things. But I want to learn the C++ preprocessor also, even if it get me that there is no "good solution" for the problem I want to solve :)

Comment: Ok,  don't `PRINT_SQUARE` need an argument in your main? .. oh I didn't see the MAP-thingy... perhaps the preprocessor missed it too :-)

Comment: The argument is given inside the macro, my first code works well, the second do not because of the end of recursion is not working...

Comment: Some things: look at [Boost.Preprocessor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html). There's also some articles about building things with the preprocessor than can help with understanding how it works. Finally, you'd only need a macro to implement something like `IS_VALID((a, b), a + b)` which would expand to the code you wrote earlier.

Comment: For actually writing things with the preprocessor, use the `-E` flag (GCC and Clang, I can't remember MSVC's, but I think it's also `-E` or `/E`). It tells the compiler to spit out the preprocessed source instead of compiling it all the way.

Comment: I'm missing `MAP_0` ? Since it's not a macro, the preprocessor will leave that token untouched, and the compiler doesn't have it defined.

Comment: @Justin that is exactly the kind of MACRO I want to write, however I have no idea how to do it, I dont know how to strip parenthesis etc etc ^^

Comment: @MSalters MAP_0 should not be writen by the preprocessor since it is skipped away by MAP_NEXT0

Comment: @AntoineMorrier: Then why is it there in the first place?!  And for that matter, since `MAP_NEXT0` discards its first argument as well, why does it have an `end`? And where's the recursion? This is just preprocessor cargo cult coding.

Comment: Because here I only treat one and only one argument. The idea is to call the same MACRO x times until we get the `()` argument that call the `MAP_END` macro that allows to stop the recursion

Comment: @AntoineMorrier Again, see Boost.Preprocessor. It allows you to do all this and more. If you don't want to use it, that's fine, but I'd still recommend looking into it and understanding how it does what it does

Comment: @Justin that is what I am currently doing, there is a chapter than explains technics used inside it. Thanks for the link :)